# How to use a custom collection created from winrt::observable_vector_base

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

Inside of my C++/WinRT project I am trying to use the example vector created here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/collections

```
struct MyObservableVector :
    implements<MyObservableVector, IObservableVector<float>, IVector<float>, IVectorView<float>, IIterable<float>>,
    winrt::observable_vector_base<MyObservableVector, float>
{
    auto& get_container() const noexcept
    {
        return m_values;
    }

    auto& get_container() noexcept
    {
        return m_values;
    }

private:
    std::vector<float> m_values{ 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f };
};
```

So for example, how would somebody use this vector inside the `PhotoEditor` demo app? (https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-photo-editor)

Let's say you wanted to declare it as part of the `Photo.idl` `Photo.h` `Photo.cpp` ViewModel?

Comment: What's the usage of your vector here? The demo seems already contained the photo collection for binding.

Comment: The goal would be to call get_container() from MainPage.cpp to get the underlying vector.

Comment: use get_container to get the exist m_values does not make sense to photo project there. What's the value's usage?